# Recursively calculate SHA256 sum of all files in directory using OpenSSL

Tags: c, directory, openssl

I am trying to recursively calculate SHA256 sum of all files in directory using OpenSSL.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>

#define _MAX_LINE_ 256

int sha256_file (char* path, char output[65]){

    FILE* file = fopen(path, "rb");
    unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    const int bufSize = 32768;
    char* buffer = malloc(bufSize);
    int bytesRead = 0;
    SHA256_CTX sha256;

    if(!file)
        return -1;
        
    if(!buffer)
        return -1;

    SHA256_Init(&sha256);

    while((bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, bufSize, file))){
        SHA256_Update(&sha256, buffer, bytesRead);
    }

    SHA256_Final(hash, &sha256);

    sha256_hash_string(hash, output);

    fclose(file);
    free(buffer);

    return 0;
}      

void sha256_hash_string (unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH], char outputBuffer[65]){
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++){
        sprintf(outputBuffer + (i * 2), "%02x", (unsigned char)hash[i]);
    }

    outputBuffer[64] = 0;
}


void traverse_dirs(char* base_path){

    char path[_MAX_LINE_];
    struct dirent* dp;
    DIR* dir = opendir(base_path);
    unsigned char file_sha[65];
    char* md5_command;

    if(!dir)
        return;

    while((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
        if(strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") != 0){
            
            // calculate the sha256 sum of the file
            sha256_file(dp->d_name, file_sha);

            // print the name of the file followed by the sha256 sum
            printf("%s -> %s\n", dp->d_name, file_sha);

            strcpy(path, base_path);
            strcat(path, "/");
            strcat(path, dp->d_name);

            traverse_dirs(path);

        }
    }

    closedir(dir);

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    if(argc < 2){
        printf("Usage: <executable> <dirname>\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
        
    traverse_dirs(argv[1]);

    return 0;

}
```

The `sha256_file()` function produces the correct sha256sum for each file, as I have tested manually.

The `traverse_dirs()` function also works fine, as it correctly prints the contents of the directory provided.

The problem is they don't work together. I have figured out that the file is not opening correctly in the `sha256_file()` function (fopen returns NULL) but I don't get why. If I use it manually on every file, it works just fine.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Looks like you are only passing the file name to `sha256_file()` not the complete path so it cannot find the file when it tries to open it. You also have a memory leak in that situation as you `malloc()` buffer but return without freeing it.

Comment: @tinman Yes, that is true. How will I pass the complete path to the function? Any ideas on that?

Comment: You already create the full path when you call `traverse_dirs()`, so you could move your `sha256_file()` call to just before that and use `path` as the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `sha256_file(dp->d_name, file_sha)` won't work because you are not in the directory that contains that name. You need to instead use the path that you construct in `path[]`.

You should only be calling `sha256_file(path)` if `path` is a regular file or a symbolic link (if you want to process symbolic links — your call), only calling `traverse_dirs(path)` if `path` is a directory, or doing nothing with the entry otherwise. You can check for those using `d_type`. See the man page for dirent.

For efficiency, you could have just one `path[]` that gets passed through the `traverse()` calls, appending to `path[]` for each entry. That would use much less stack space, and would be faster as well with much less copying. You would also allocate `file_sha[]` only in the block that computes the SHA-256, so you're not wasting recursing stack space on that either.

Something like:

```c
void traverse_dirs(char* path, size_t end) {
    DIR* dir = opendir(path);
    if (dir == NULL)
        return;
    path[end] = '/';
    struct dirent* dp;
    while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (dp->d_name[0] == '.' && (dp->d_name[1] == 0 ||
             (dp->d_name[1] == '.' && dp->d_name[2] == 0)))
            continue;
        strcpy(path + end + 1, dp->d_name);
        if (dp->d_type == DT_REG || dp->d_type == DT_LNK) {
            unsigned char file_sha[65];
            sha256_file(path, file_sha);
            printf("%s -> %s\n", path, file_sha);
        }
        else if (dp->d_type == DT_DIR)
            traverse_dirs(path, end + 1 + strlen(dp->d_name));
    }
    closedir(dir);
}
```

which would be called initially with `*path` having enough space for the maximum path size plus one, and containing the path to open as a directory. The second argument would be the length of the path, or zero if the path is the root, `"/"` (to avoid double slashes). You should get the maximum path length from limits.h as `PATH_MAX`, assuming your system is POSIX compliant. Or if not, 32K should be safe. 256 isn't.

If your `struct dirent` has `d_namlen`, then you can use that instead of the `strlen()`. Or if you have `stpcpy()`, you can use that instead of `strcpy()` and compute the end from its return value. You can also consider guarding against writing past the end of `path[]`. If you don't mind globals, `path` could be a global and not pass the same pointer unnecessarily in every call.

Move your `malloc()` after the first `return`, and it if it fails, close the open file before returning. Or just allocate the 32K on the stack. That's a small amount for the stack.